# How to fetch AWS S3 DeleteMarkers in C# SDK?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, sdk

I have a versioning-enabled S3 bucket.
I'm accessing it via the `AWSSDK.S3` Nuget package.

I can't see anyway to acquire information about deleted versions of files, or versions of files for which the latest record is a Delete Marker?

Is it possible to do this using that SDK?
What about with some *other* SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Ah. Found it - it's the Request/Response/Method collection called `ListVersions`.